# Finding the set of vectors that are perpendicular to a given vector in three dimensions

Tags: solution-verification, vectors

Below is a problem I made up and did. I believe my solution is correct but
I have some doubts because my solution effectively has two free variable
and I expected only one free variable. Is my solution correct? I am also open to style comments.

Problem:

Find all vectors that are perpendicular to the vector $(1,2,3)$ and have
length $1$.

Answer:

If two vectors are perpendicular then there dot product is $0$.
\begin{align*}
(u_1,u_2,u_3) \cdot ( 1,2,3) &= 0 \\
u_1 + 2u_2 + 3u_3 &= 0 \\
\sqrt{ u_1^2 + u_2^2 + u_3^2 } &= 1 \\
u_1^2 + u_2^2 + u_3^2 &= 1 \\
u_3^2 &= 1 - u_1^2 - u_2^2 \\
u_1 + 2u_2 + 3\left( \sqrt{  1 - u_1^2 - u_2^2 }\right)  &= 0 \\
\end{align*}
Now we simplify the equation.
\begin{align*}
u_1 + 2u_2 &= -3 \sqrt{  1 - u_1^2 - u_2^2 } \\
(u_1+2u_2)^2 &= 9( 1 - u_1^2 - u_2^2 ) \\
u_1^2 + 4u_1 u_2 + 4u_2^2 &= 9 - 9u_1^2 - 9u_2^2 \\
10u_1^2 + 4u_1 u_2 + 4u_2^2 &= 9  - 9u_2^2 \\
10u_1^2 + 4u_1 u_2 + 13u_2^2 &= 9  \\
\end{align*}
Hence my answer is:
$$ (x,y,z) \text{ where } x,y,z \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and }
10x^2 + 4xy + 13y^2 = 9  $$

Here is an updated answer:
$$ (x,y, 1 - x^2 - y^2) \text{ where } x,y \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and }
10x^2 + 4xy + 13y^2 = 9  $$
Is it right now?

Here is an updated answer:
$$ (x,y, -\sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}) \text{ where } x,y \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and }
10x^2 + 4xy + 13y^2 = 9  $$
Is it right now?

ow, I will attempt to to a partial check of the answer. Observe that:
$$ (1,2,-\dfrac{5}{3}) \cdot ( 1,2,3) = 1 + 4 - 5 = 0 $$
Hence $(1,2,-\dfrac{5}{3})$ is perpendicular to $(1,2,3)$. However, it
does not have length $1$. We can adjust the vector os that it does.
\begin{align*}
\left|(1,2,-\dfrac{5}{3})\right| &= \sqrt{ 1 + 4 + \dfrac{25}{9}} \\
\left|(1,2,-\dfrac{5}{3})\right| &= \sqrt{ \dfrac{9+36+25}{9}}
 = \sqrt{ \dfrac{70}{9}} \\
\left|(1,2,-\dfrac{5}{3})\right| &= \dfrac{ \sqrt{70} }{ 3 }
\end{align*}
Hence, we claim that
$\dfrac{  (1,2,-\dfrac{5}{3})  }{\dfrac{ \sqrt{70} }{ 3 } }
= \dfrac{ (3,6, -5)}{\sqrt{70}}$ is
a perpendicular vector. Is it of the form of my answer? We have:
\begin{align*}
x &= \dfrac{3}{ \sqrt{70}} \\
y &= \dfrac{6}{ \sqrt{70}} \\
1 - x^2 - y^2 &= 1 - \dfrac{9}{70} - \dfrac{36}{70} \\
%
1 - x^2 - y^2 &= \dfrac{ 70  - 45}{70} = \dfrac{ 25}{70} \\
-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} &= -\dfrac{ 5 }{ \sqrt{ 70} }
\end{align*}
Hence it checks in this case.

Comment: A good habit to get into is to check your answer with a few special cases. For instance, taking $x=z=0$ in your final equation indicates that $(x,y,z)=(3/\sqrt{10},0,0)$ is a solution—but this is neither a unit vector nor orthogonal to $(1,2,3)$. So something has gone wrong…

Comment: @Semiclassical I now agree that something is wrong. It would be of help to me if you or somebody else told me what I did wrong. However, I am going to work on it some more myself.

Comment: The classic mistake: if $u^3=1-u_1^2-u_2^2$, then $u_3=\pm\sqrt{1-u_1^2-u_2^2}$.

Comment: Just by using plain algebra i dont know if its possible to reach a one parameter parametrization. Using trigonometry and polar coordinates you can express your answer in terms of only one parameter. Although in order to do this i think you'll need to do a change of coordinates.

Comment: @HeldertV If my updated solution is now correct, I am happy. If it is  still wrong, I am not happy.

Comment: Using just the negative root only gives half of the solutions, that is the reason because @Taladris used $\pm$ in his answer.

Comment: @HeldertV I do not agree with you because any solution vector must satisfy the equation $u_1 + 2u_2 + 3u_3 = 0$. Assuming that $(u_1, u_2,u_3)$ is a valid solution to the problem and $u_3$ is not zero than  $(u_1, u_2,-u_3)$ will not be a valid solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way is to think geometrically: let $a=(1,2,3)$. You may see $a$ as a vector with its initial point at the origin. Then the set of all vectors that are perpendicular to $a$ and whose initial point is at the origin form a plan $P$. Its equation is $x+2y+3z=0$ since $a$ has to be perpendicular to it and $(0,0,0)$ is on the plane.

Moreover, if $v=(x,y,z)$ is a unit vector, then $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, so $(x,y,z)$ is on the unit sphere $S$ in space. Therefore, the set that describes the components $(x,y,z)$ of the unit vectors that are perpendicular to $a$ is the intersection of the plane $P$ and the sphere $S$, which is a circle. It can be described by the system

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{rcl}
x^2+y^2+z^2 & = & 1 \\
x+2y+3z & = & 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

In my opinion, this is a good description since it gives you all the information you need. Loosely speaking, an equation in space describes a surface and a curve can be described as the intersection of two surfaces.

Alternatively, you may want to describe the circle using parametric equations. A figure would help to understand the construction, but it is identical to the usual parametrization of the unit circle in trigonometry: choose two perpendicular unit vectors $t$ and $n$ in $P$. Then, every unit vector perpendicular to $a$ can be described as

$$(x,y,z)=\cos(\theta)t+\sin(\theta)n$$

for some $\theta$ in $[0,2\pi)$. For example, $t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(-2,1,0)$ and $n=\frac{a\times t}{\|a\times t\|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{70}}(-3,-6,5)$.